# how to add pagination for wordpress taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, pagination, posts

```
 $term_list = get_terms( 'artwork-artists', 
                        array( 'orderby'=>$orderby, 
                        'order'=>$order, 
                        'hide_empty'=>0, 
                        'number'=>$number, 
                        'include'=>$includes, 
                        'exclude'=> $excludes
                        )
                    ); 
 if(!empty( $instance['shuffle'])) {
    foreach( $term_list as $term ) { 
        $term_link = get_term_link($term->slug, 'artwork- artists'); 
        $t_id = $term->term_id;
        $term_meta = get_option($term->taxonomy .  $t_id . "_image_term_id"); 
        }
 }
```

I have post type artwork it has taxonomy of artwork-artists need pagination for artists taxonomies